# Elementary OS: Accidentally installed Ubuntu Login Screen

Tags: ubuntu, login, elementary-os, theme

When I restarted my Elementary OS Laptop today I was shocked, because I was on an Ubuntu-styled glitching Login Screen. I guess I accidentally installed it, by trying to get ubuntu-tweak-tools on my Laptop. I need to get my old Elementary OS Login-Screen back. (All the other things are still elementary. Only the login screen changed it style)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `unity-tweak-tool` is not suited for tweaking elementary OS. Some things *might* work, but it's completly unsupported as it is written for tweaking the `Unity` desktop environment - elementary is using `Pantheon`, a desktop written from scratch.

Installing `unity-tweak-tool` pulled in a package called `unity` (a *metapackage*), which in turn pulled in core packages for the Unity DE. You don't need most of these packages, but it won't hurt you either, so there is not a real problem - save for a package called `unity-greeter`. This is a greeter for LightDM (the software behind your login screen) and it overwrites elementary's default greeter.

To remove the greeter, just run this command from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-greeter
```